# fortran integer to double

Tags: integer, fortran, double, truncate

I have a doubt about fortran. In the following code:

```
program p
integer num
real*8 d
num=111
d=dble(num/4) 
print*, d 
end program p
```

I get  27.000000000000000. Is it because num is an integer and so num/4 have to be the same type? 
It is a part of another code I have to translate in Matlab: in this particular case can I translate it as num/4 truncated?

```
floor(num/4)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note, do not use real*8, it might not actually do what you think it does. Use the `real(kind=rk)` notation and pick the kind rk with `selected_real_kind`. Your problem is, that you do the dble around the division. That is, first the division is done (which is an integer division as both arguments are integers) and then casts the result into a real. Instead you could for example do: `d=real(num,kind=rk)/4`. Better yet, maybe something like this: `d=0.25_rk*num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get `27.000000000000000` because `num` is an integer, thus `num\4` is an integer.

To get a real precision result, you would simply write `d=1./4*num`

Yes, in Matlab this would be `floor(num/4)` as `num` is a double precision float unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Or `num/4.`, etc.